# Pyplot - automatically setting x axis range to min, max x values passed to plotting function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating a plot with a method similar to the following:

```
import pyplot as plt

for x_list in x_list_of_lists:
   plt.plot(y_list, x_list)

plt.show()
```

The range of the x axis seems to get set to the range of the first list of x values that is passed to plt.plot(). Is there a way to have pyplot automatically set the lower limit of the x axis to the lowest value in all of the x_list variables passed to it (plus a bit of leeway), and to have it do the same for the upper limit, using the highest x value passed to plot (plus a bit of leeway)? Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Confusingly, your `y_list` contains the values being plotted along the `x-axis`. If you want matplotlib to use values from `x_list` as `x-coordinates`, then you should call

```
plt.plot(x_list, y_list)
```

Maybe this is the root of your problem.
By default matplotlib sets the `x` and `y` limits big enough to include all the data plotted.

So with this change, matplotlib will now be using `x_list` as `x-coordinates`, and will automatically set the limits of the `x-axis` to be wide enough to display all the `x-coordinates` specified in `x_list_of_lists`.

---

However, if you wish to adjust the `x` limits, you could use the [plt.xlim function](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html).

So, to set the lower limit of the `x-axis` to the lowest value in all of the `x_list` variables (and similarly for the upper limit), you'd do this:

```
xmin = min([min(x_list) for x_list in x_list_of_lists])-delta
xmax = max([max(x_list) for x_list in x_list_of_lists])+delta
plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)
```

Make sure you place this *after* all the calls to `plt.plot` and (of course) before `plt.show()`.